# Trying to reduce redundancies

Tags: javascript

I wrote some code, but I am pretty sure, that this could be shorter but my brain just stopped working and therefore I want to ask you about some tipps.
The problem is, that there are kind of redundancies in the code and like I said, I am pretty sure, that some kind of loop or something could handle this problem.

This piece of code is, like the name of the function, for toggling two different contents. This is for simulating a header with two tabs and therefore to present different content, when one of the two tabs are clicked.

```js
function toggleContent() {
    if(!firstTab.classList.contains("active")) {
      firstTab.classList.add("active");
      secondTab.classList.remove("active");
      firstContent.classList.add("visible");
      secondContent.classList.remove("visible");
    } else {
      secondTab.classList.add("active");
      firstTab.classList.remove("active");
      secondContent.classList.add("visible");
      firstContent.classList.remove("visible");
    }
  }
```

Comment: `classList.toggle` method has a second argument that may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`classList` has a `toggle` method with a second argument that may help

```
function toggleContent() {
  var isFirstTabActive = firstTab.classList.contains("active");

  firstTab.classList.toggle("active", !isFirstTabActive);
  secondTab.classList.toggle("active", isFirstTabActive);
  firstContent.classList.toggle("visible", !isFirstTabActive);
  secondContent.classList.toggle("visible", isFirstTabActive);
}
```

This doesn't take into consideration the possibility of even shorter code - however, as the HTML is a mystery, this will do

Comment: Well, I should have read the api-documentation of classList a bit more. Thank you, thats exactly what I needed!